# Saving and a fast.ai v1 ULMFiT model. to/from disk

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

Simple Question.

[I have been doing experiments with ULMFiT](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/examples/text.ipynb)

Yet I do not see a way to save and load models to/from disk easily? There is a load method available to the RNNLearner class that is created in this example, but it is not documented.

I have tried several methods and none of them work. Is there something i am missing? There do not seem to be any examples of a fast ai v1 model loaded from disk.

Answer (score 1):

The [RNNLearner() class](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/fastai/text/learner.py#L48) has a `save_encoder()` method. For example, if your `RNNLearner()` object is called `learn`, then the call invoke the `save_encoder()` method would be: `learn.save_encoder(name='my_model_name')`

Also, the `RNNLearner()` class inherits from the [Learner() class](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/fastai/basic_train.py#L129), which itself contains a `save()` method.

Both the `save_encoder()` and `save()` methods have a `name` argument which takes a string that will serve as the name under which your model is saved.